# Calling schedule with ScheduleJobs

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I've been trying to figure out how to call the ScheduleJobs methods within Quartz.Net, but struggling to create the correct parameters it's expecting.

[image: ScheduleJobs Parameters]

Here's what I've tried:

```
IJobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<ReportJob>()
    .WithIdentity("theJob")
    .Build();
ITrigger everydayTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("everydayTrigger")
    // fires 
    .WithCronSchedule("0 0 12 1/1 * ?")
    // start immediately
    .StartAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Year))
    .Build();
ITrigger yearlyTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("yearlyTrigger")
    // fires 
    .WithCronSchedule("0 0 12 1 1 ? *")
    // start immediately
    .StartAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Year))
    .Build();
var dictionary = new Dictionary<IJobDetail, ISet<ITrigger>>();
dictionary.Add(jobDetail, new HashSet<ITrigger>() { everydayTrigger, yearlyTrigger });
sched.ScheduleJobs((dictionary, true); // is a cast possible here to IDictionary?
```

Other attempts;

```
sched.ScheduleJobs(new [] { jobDetail, new[] { afternoonTrigger } }, true);
```

&&

```
sched.ScheduleJobs(new[] { new KeyValuePair<IJobDetail, ITrigger>()}.ToDictionary<IJobDetail, Quartz.Collection.ISet<ITrigger>(), true);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you use the collections from Quartz's namespace, here's a version of your code that compiles with **Quartz 2.x**:

```
IJobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<ReportJob>()
    .WithIdentity("theJob")
    .Build();
ITrigger everydayTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("everydayTrigger")
    // fires 
    .WithCronSchedule("0 0 12 1/1 * ?")
    // start immediately
    .StartAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Year))
    .Build();
ITrigger yearlyTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("yearlyTrigger")
    // fires 
    .WithCronSchedule("0 0 12 1 1 ? *")
    // start immediately
    .StartAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Year))
    .Build();
var dictionary = new Dictionary<IJobDetail, Quartz.Collection.ISet<ITrigger>>();
dictionary.Add(jobDetail, new Quartz.Collection.HashSet<ITrigger>()
                            {
                                everydayTrigger,
                                yearlyTrigger
                            });
sched.ScheduleJobs(dictionary, true);
```

Please not that for Quartz 3 you should use the BCL types, like `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>`, there's no need to use Quartz's custom types anymore.

Comment: I keep getting cannot resolve "Collection". I'm on version 3.x, .Net Framework 4.7. What am i missing?

Comment: Here's an example: https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz.Examples/01_SimpleJobScheduler/SimpleJobSchedulerExample.cs