# Schedule multiple jobs in Quartz.Net

Tags: .net, quartz.net

I am a beginner in Quartz.Net.
How can I add multiple jobs in a scheduler?

For the sake of learning I am using Console Application.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're new to Quartz.Net I would suggest you to start with Jay Vilalta's [Blog](http://jayvilalta.com/blog/) and the old [one](http://jvilalta.blogspot.co.uk/) where you can find loads of tutorials and useful infos about Quartz.Net.

If you want to schedule multiple jobs in your console application you can simply call `Scheduler.ScheduleJob` (**IScheduler**) passing the job and the trigger you've previously created:

```
IJobDetail firstJob = JobBuilder.Create<FirstJob>()
               .WithIdentity("firstJob")
               .Build();

ITrigger firstTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                 .WithIdentity("firstTrigger")
                 .StartNow()
                 .WithCronSchedule("0 * 8-22 * * ?")
                 .Build();


IJobDetail secondJob = JobBuilder.Create<SecondJob>()
               .WithIdentity("secondJob")
               .Build();

ITrigger secondTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                 .WithIdentity("secondTrigger")
                 .StartNow()
                 .WithCronSchedule("0 0/2 * 1/1 * ? *")
                 .Build();

Scheduler.ScheduleJob(firstJob, firstTrigger);
Scheduler.ScheduleJob(secondJob, secondTrigger);
```

You can download a working example [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=669adf1af64df389&resid=669ADF1AF64DF389!245&parid=669ADF1AF64DF389!155&authkey=!).

UPDATE:

If you want to pause and/or restart a job you can use `PauseJob` and `ResumeJob` (you can do the same for a trigger with `PauseTrigger` and `ResumeTrigger`).

This is a sample:

```
private static void Test001(IScheduler Scheduler)
{
    IJobDetail firstJob = JobBuilder.Create<FirstJob>()
                   .WithIdentity("firstJob")
                   .Build();

    ITrigger firstTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                     .WithIdentity("firstTrigger")
                     .StartNow()
                     .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(1).RepeatForever())
                     .Build();


    IJobDetail secondJob = JobBuilder.Create<SecondJob>()
                   .WithIdentity("secondJob")
                   .Build();

    ITrigger secondTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                     .WithIdentity("secondTrigger")
                     .StartNow()
                     .WithSimpleSchedule(x=>x.WithIntervalInSeconds(1).RepeatForever())
                     .Build();


    Scheduler.ScheduleJob(firstJob, firstTrigger);
    Scheduler.ScheduleJob(secondJob, secondTrigger);

    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    if (i == 100)
    {
        Scheduler.PauseJob(new JobKey("firstJob"));
    }
    else if (i == 200)
    {
        Scheduler.ResumeJob(new JobKey("firstJob"));
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me another thing.  Suppose I have two jobs running at same intervals.  Then can I pause any one job for sometime and again let it run?

Comment: Glad I've helped. I've updated my answer with more info. Have a look at `PauseJob` and `ResumeJob`. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  But the above code is not fulfilling my requirement.  I have a scenario where I have suppose two  jobs running at similar intervals let it be 30 seconds. Then suppose a job is paused suddenly at 15 seconds for certain reason while the other job is continued to run.  Now I want that after resuming, the first job should start at 16 seconds i.e., where it was left.  Will Misfire help?

Comment: what is the meaning of this "0 * 8-22 * * ?" and "0 0/2 * 1/1 * ? *"

Comment: @Mou: That is a [cron expressoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). You can check the result of that expression [here](http://www.cronmaker.com/).

Comment: How can? Firstly, I want to add jobs to scheduler. Secondly, I only want to add one trigger. And finally, I run all jobs with one trigger.

Answer (score 8):

I use this solution:

```
IJobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder
    .Create<ReportJob>()
    .WithIdentity("theJob")
    .Build();

ITrigger everydayTrigger = TriggerBuilder
    .Create()
    .WithIdentity("everydayTrigger")
    // fires 
    .WithCronSchedule("0 0 12 1/1 * ?")
    // start immediately
    .StartAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Year))
    .Build();
ITrigger yearlyTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("yearlyTrigger")
    // fires 
    .WithCronSchedule("0 0 12 1 1 ? *")
    // start immediately
    .StartAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Year))
    .Build();

var dictionary = new Dictionary<IJobDetail, Quartz.Collection.ISet<ITrigger>>();
dictionary.Add(jobDetail, new Quartz.Collection.HashSet<ITrigger>()
                          {
                              everydayTrigger,
                              yearlyTrigger
                          });
sched.ScheduleJobs(dictionary, true);
```

from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20419575/1676736

Answer (score 1):

What you want to accomplish is very simple:

```cs
ISchedulerFactory schFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
IScheduler sch = schFactory.GetScheduler();

sch.Start();

//Repeat the code below for as many jobs you'd like
//creating jobs and triggers for them. 
//If they fire at the same time, just one ITrigger is needed .....
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
    .WithIdentity("myJob", null)
    .Build();

ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                 .Create()
                 .WithSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.RepeatMinutelyForever())
                 .ForJob(job)
                 .WithIdentity(job.Key.Name + "Trigger")
                 .Build();

sch.AddJob(trigger);
```

Comment: It's not working.I am getting exception for the second job as "trigger doesn't reference given job".

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add jobs and triggers dynamically you can try the following code.

`
using Quartz;

```
public Task DoSomething(IScheduler schedule, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var job = JobBuilder.Create<StartTripJob>()
                        .WithIdentity("name", "group")
                        .Build();

    var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("name", "group")
        .StartNow()
        .Build();

    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger, ct);
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

For Quartz.AspNetCore with AspNetCoreWebApi projects, in Program.cs add this:

```
using Quartz;
...
builder.Services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
    var jobKey1 = new JobKey("ContractUpdaterJob");
    q.AddJob<ContractUpdaterJob>(opts => opts.WithIdentity(jobKey1));
    q.AddTrigger(opts => opts
        .ForJob(jobKey1)
        .WithIdentity("ContractUpdaterJob-trigger")
        .WithCronSchedule("0 0 12-19 * * ?")
    );

    var jobKey2 = new JobKey("SpaceMaintenanceJob");
    q.AddJob<SpaceMaintenanceJob>(opts => opts.WithIdentity(jobKey2));
    q.AddTrigger(opts => opts
        .ForJob(jobKey2)
        .WithIdentity("SpaceMaintenanceJob-trigger")
        .WithCronSchedule("0 0 10 * * ?")
    );

});
```