# C#:How to schedule multiple routine by Quartz.net at different time of the day once

Tags: c#, quartz.net

i know how to fire my one routine every day at specific time of day. here is the code.

```
IScheduler sched = null;
//construct a scheduler factory
ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

//get a scheduler
sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
sched.Start();

IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<frmMain>()
.WithIdentity("Job", "group")
.Build();

ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
.WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
 (s =>
    s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
   .OnEveryDay()
   .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(19, 07))
 )
.Build();

sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

suppose now i am in scenario that i need to trigger many routine at different time of the day once.

say routine1 should fire at 08:00, routine2 should fire at 15:00 and routine2 should fire at 18:00

now give me suggestion how could i fire different routine at different time of the day. thanks

Comment: Wouldn't you just write a trigger for each one?

Comment: As I've pointed out over multiple of your and Thomas' collective 1500+ questions, can you put a _little_ more effort in the phrasing of your question? Sentences start with a capital letter, also 'I' is capitalized in English. Also read [ask] and share your research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like stuartd stated, you need multiple triggers for your job(routine2). I would also suggest to use `CronTrigger` instead of `SimpleTrigger`. You can easily create a `CronTrigger` with:

```
var trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithDescription(name)
                .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(15, 0))
                .Build();

var trigger2 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithDescription(name)
                .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(18, 0))
                .Build();
```

And then just schedule your job with the 2 triggers:

```
sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger1);
sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger2);
```

Comment: do i need to create multiple job and trigger ?

Comment: No, you just schedule the same job with trigger1 and trigger2.

Comment: i found this link is good http://stackoverflow.com/a/21550355/728750  for my scenario.

Comment: i have to schedule same job with two trigger when i need to call same routine twice a day in different time but if i need to call two different routine then i have to create two job and two trigger for that. this link is good for that http://stackoverflow.com/a/21550355/728750