# How to create multiple jobs in Quartz/Hangfire dynamically using MVC C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, quartz.net, hangfire

I am new to [Quartz.net/hangfire](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet). I have a requirement that I need to schedule multiple reports through UI by the client as per their convenient timing.

We have almost 30 clients, and each client has 20-25 reports. Clients have access to the portal and they can configure their report timing by any day/monthly/yearly.

For example, if client A scheduled 5 reports:

```
report a ---> daily @ 10PM
report b ---> monthly once on date 02 @ 10AM
report c ---> yearly once on date 30/june @ 5PM
report d ---> daily @ 12PM
report e ---> monthly once on date 02 @ 10AM
```

In the same way, all clients have the privilege to configure their reports respectively from the UI.

Could you please help me on **how to create multiple jobs dynamically** from UI using Quartz.net/Hangfire?

Comment: [Schedule multiple jobs in Quartz.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21550355/13664939)

Comment: Hi @gurkan, Please correct me if I am wrong. If I need to add a new job and trigger (3rd job, Since in the example you provided it already has 2 jobs) from a UI which will be constructed in an ActionResult and the statement -> Scheduler.ScheduleJob(thirdjob, thirdTrigger); needs to be called isn't?

Comment: I just shared the anwser. TBH; I'm not experienced about that library and I don't want to mislead you. I think you should ask to [discussion board](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/discussions).