# How to dynamically create background tasks using Quartz.Net based on schedules inserted to database?

Tags: c#, .net-core, quartz.net, background-service

I am implementing multiple background tasks/jobs in .NET Core.
What I want to do is:

1. Create and insert schedules in database.
2. Create timed background task based on schedules created in 1.
   I'm using [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) package.
   1 Is done, so I need help to create background tasks dynamically.

I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527841/schedule-multiple-jobs-in-quartz-net/21550355#21550355) but multiple jobs are not dynamically created.

What I did is as below:

An extension for configuring quartz:

```
public static class QuartzConfigurationExtension
{
    public static void AddJobAndTriggers<T>(this IServiceCollectionQuartzConfigurator quartz, IConfiguration config) where T : IJob
    {
        string jobName = typeof(T).Name;

        var configKey = $"Quartz:{jobName}";
        var cronSchedule = config[configKey];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cronSchedule))
        {
            throw new Exception($"No Quartz.NET cron schedule found for job in configuration at {configKey}");
        }

        var jobKey = new JobKey(jobName);
        quartz.AddJob<T>(opts => opts.WithIdentity(jobKey));
        quartz.AddTrigger(opts => opts
            .ForJob(jobKey)
            .WithIdentity(jobName + "-trigger")
            .WithCronSchedule(cronSchedule)
        );
    }
}
```

Job Class:

```
public class DataSyncJob : IJob
{
    public DataSyncJob()
    {

    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Startup: (as is) works fine for one single job

```
services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
    q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
    q.AddJobAndTrigger<DataSyncJob>(Configuration);
});
services.AddQuartzHostedService(q => q.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);
```

Startup: (expected) dynamically get schedules from database and loop to create scheduled jobs. *****>> Is it possible?**

```
var db = services.BuildServiceProvider()
    .GetService<dbContext>();

var schedules = db.SyncSchedule.ToListAsync();

foreach (var schedule in schedules.Result)
{
    services.AddQuartz(q =>
    {
        q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
        q.AddJobAndTrigger<DataSyncJob>(Configuration); **// how to create generic Job classes based on schedules?**
    });
    services.AddQuartzHostedService(q => q.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't create jobs dynamically inside `Startup`. This code shouldn't talk to a database. Instead, I suggest creating another job to handle it. This is, connect with your database, get all the information and create more jobs.

In order to manage them use the `IScheduler`. You get it via `context.Scheduler` of the `Execute` method. This contains everything you need like `ScheduleJob`, `DeleteJob` etc.