# C# .NET7.0 Core Quartz Schedule two DI jobs from two different custom jobFactories

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, quartz-scheduler, .net-7.0

In my .NET7.0 Core with Quartz web app, I try to run two cronjobs that use dependency injection.

Each of the cronjobs is constructed with a custom job factory within my program.cs file.

When scheduled alone, each cronjob works as expected.

But as soon as I try to schedule both cronjobs, only the one that is scheduled second is executed, but twice.

First to the trigger time of cronjobA, then to the trigger time of cronjobB.

Therefore, I assume the second cronjob overwrites the first one.

How can I avoid this behaviour and run both jobs?

My code looks like this:

**program.cs**

```
[...]
await ScheduleCronJobs(connectionString);

app.Run();


//=====================================

static async Task ScheduleCronJobs(string connectionString)
{
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = BuildServiceProvider(connectionString);

    await ScheduleCronJobA(serviceProvider);
    await ScheduleCronJobB(serviceProvider);
}

static ServiceProvider BuildServiceProvider(string connectionString)
{
    ServiceCollection serviceCollection = new();
    serviceCollection.TryAddTransient<CronJobA>();
    serviceCollection.TryAddTransient<CronJobB>();
    serviceCollection.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options
                    .UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
    serviceCollection.TryAddTransient<JobManager>();
    [some other services]

    return serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
}



static async Task ScheduleCronJobA(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    NameValueCollection props = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "quartz.serializer.type", "binary" }
    };

    StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
    IScheduler sched = await factory.GetScheduler();
    sched.JobFactory = new CronJobAJobFactory(serviceProvider);

    await sched.Start();

    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<CronJobA>()
                                .WithIdentity("cronJobA", "group1")
                                .Build();
    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                        .WithIdentity("cronJobATrigger", "group1")
                                        .StartAt(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5))
                                        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                                            .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
                                            .RepeatForever())
                                        .Build();
    await sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
```

Also here, cronjob B looks almost the same, just

```
sched.JobFactory = new CronJobBJobFactory(serviceProvider);
```

,

```
.WithIdentity("cronJobB", "group1")
```

and

```
.WithIdentity("cronJobBTrigger", "group2")
.StartAt(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(7))
```

are different.

I also tried to schedule both tasks in one scheduling task with only one

```
NameValueCollection props = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "quartz.serializer.type", "binary" }
    };

    StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
    IScheduler sched = await factory.GetScheduler();
```

section, the result stays unfortunately the same.

Putting

```
await sched.Start();
```

at the end of the method does not do the trick either.

**CronjobA factory** (B looks the same, just with `CronJobB` instead of `CronJobA`)

```
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Spi;

namespace MyApp.Jobs.CronJobs.CronJobA
{
    public class CronJobAJobFactory : IJobFactory
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public CronJobAJobFactory (IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
        {
            return _serviceProvider.GetService<CronJobAJob>();
        }

        public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
        {
            var disposable = job as IDisposable;
            disposable?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**CronjobA:**

```
[...]
using Quartz;

namespace MyApp.Jobs.CronJobs.CronJobA
{
    public class JobA: IJob
    {
        private readonly JobManager _jobManager;

        public TrackPositionAssignJob(JobManager jobManager)
        {
            _jobManager = jobManager;
        }

        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": " JobA started. );
            //Do something with _jobManager
        }
    }
}
```

The Quartz documentation does not seem to cover this usecase, as mentioned, as long as I am running only one of both cronjobs, everything works like a charme.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is await both threads in `ScheduleChronJob()` like this:

```cs
var tasks = new List<Task>
{
    ScheduleCronJobA(serviceProvider),
    ScheduleCronJobB(serviceProvider),
};
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

You can do the same thing by building the list as well with `tasks.Add()` if you don't know how many Tasks will be started.

Comment: Thank you, and probably I am missing some point here, but my issue stays the same with this approach: only the respective second task is executed, but to the scheduled times of both cronJobA and cronJobB.

Comment: Maybe try following this pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527841/schedule-multiple-jobs-in-quartz-net