# Quartz .NET Run multiple Tasks

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, quartz.net

I used Quartz .NET in my ASP .NET MVC 4 Webapplication to be able to start longrunning Tasks. The Long Running Task should start within a Controller Method after a POST, not with Application_Start. My Code works great, but only if no other Task is running, otherwise the running task stops. How can i run multiple Tasks at the same time and with the same IJob implemented Class? Is Quartz .NET the right Framework for that Use Case?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Processfile(HttpPostedFileBase file) {
   var groupName = "Group";
   var jobId = "processJob" + Guid.NewGuid();

   // defines the job
   IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ProcessJob>()
    .WithIdentity(jobId, groupName)
    .UsingJobData(parameters)
    .Build();

   // defines the trigger
   ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
     .WithIdentity("processTrigger" + Guid.NewGuid(), groupName)
     .WithPriority(1)
     .StartNow()
     .Build();

  // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
  await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
  await scheduler.Start();
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, "OK");
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run multiple jobs, you can declare multiple instances of `IJobDetail` class and respective `ITrigger` objects.

For example,

```
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<Class1>.Build();
IJobDetail job2 = JobBuilder.Create<Class2>.Build();

ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                .StartNow()
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                    .WithIntervalInMinutes(1)
                    .RepeatForever())
                .Build();

ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger2", "group1")
                .StartNow()
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                    .WithIntervalInMinutes(1)
                    .RepeatForever())
                .Build();
```

Then run schedule both the jobs to the same scheduler,

```
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger1);
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(job2, trigger2);
```

and then start the scheduler

```
        scheduler.Start();
```

**OR** alternatively, use the approach of Dictionary - refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20419575) for another approach.

Answer (score 0):

The scheduler should be running in the background. Ideally you have the server process running and add jobs there when needed. Depending on your setup, running scheduler inside an ASP.NET app might be [a bad idea](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/faq.html#quartz-in-web-environment).

So seeing your code, the scheduler.Start() seems quite odd.

Answer (score 0):

You call
await scheduler.Start(); 
every time.
Instead try to start job where scheduler is defined.

```
            IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();
```

Then Build the job and trigger and call `await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);`
This way your problem should be solved.